# ImageMagick iOS image

Tags: ios, image-processing, swift3, imagemagick

I am trying to preprocess images for OCR(tesseract) on my app, I have found a great script for doing this on [Freds ImageMagick Scripts](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php) but I don't know how to use Image Magick within an iOS app let alone then run a script to do so. I have googled around and not found much to help so I'm wondering if is possible? I apologise for this being such an open question. Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: You'll need to include the [iOS](https://www.imagemagick.org/download/iOS/) packaged library, and integrate with the [MagickWand C API](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-wand.php). There's a lot of Q&A's + examples about integrating with Fred's scripts on this site.

Comment: Thank you! Thats the direction I'm looking for but still no idea how to implement what they've said in your links! Noob!